# Regex to remove consecutive characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Need a regular expression to replace the following sequence

```
Before : abbbccdd   After : abcd
```

And also if numeric data is present instead of alphabets i would like to remove the duplicates  and display

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first part, in most languages you can do something like replacing `(.)\1+` with `$1`.

The exact syntax depends on the language and the regular expression engine you are using, so check the manual for your language for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This works in PHP:

```
preg_replace('/(.)\1+/','$1',$str);
```

I'm not sure what you mean with your second question, though.